# What is the use of discovery.build() in Google API?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-api-python-client

I would like to ask about the use of discovery.build in googleapiclient.

```
from googleapiclient import discovery

credentials = Credentials(None, client_id="creds1234.apps.googleusercontent.com", client_secret="secret")
resource = discovery.build("forms", "v1", discoveryServiceUrl="https://forms.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1", credentials = credentials)
```

I've been trying to use this resource, but I could not understand what it really does. I've checked the documentation but what I understand about it is that it populates the definitions for the api methods and functions that I've been using, in this example, the Forms API.

I thought I'd be interested about it, so what can it do?

Thank you.

Comment: The source code is public. That is usually the best source for low-level intenal documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Google provides client libraries (SDKs) for **all** its services.

These libraries are provided by Google in Python, Go, Java, .NET etc.

To facilitate the publication of this matrix of libraries (service*language), Google developed a mechanism that enabled automatic code-generation from service schemas. These schemas are called [Discovery documents](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis) in Google parlance . Interestingly, there's a Google service called [Discovery service](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference) too and it has a single method [`list`](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis/list) that you can try on that page. E.g. [`forms`](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis/list?apix_params=%7B%22name%22%3A%22forms%22%7D)

Given a Discovery document and [client library generator](https://github.com/google/apis-client-generator), client libraries can be generated on-the-fly.

The (open-sourced) [Python API Client Library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/README.md) includes [discovery.build](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html#build) which generates the resources for the service that you provide it.

You can simplify your code:

```py
discovery.build("forms", "v1", credentials = credentials)
```

The API Client library provides this functionality for **all** [Google services](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/dyn/index.md). If you scan the page, you'll find the `Forms` service and that it's version is `v1` (per your code). The link will take you to the API's [documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/forms_v1.html)

An alternative way to find doucmentation for a Google service (not by programming language although sometimes examples are provided), is to use [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer). You can search for and access the REST documentation for [`Google Forms`](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/). This also provides a link to the Discovery document ;-)

Note: The APIs Explorer REST documentation actually documents 2 versions of the API `v1` and `v1beta` (see left hand side). So, you can also `discovery.build("forms","v1beta",credentials=credentials)` if you need the enhanced methods.

Thanks to the Discovery mechanism and the fact that Google triggers builds for client libraries on API changes, you can be assured that the client libraries are almost always a perfect reflection of the API.

Note: Code-generation from REST-based API schemas is often done using [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) (aka Open API). Google Discovery predates swagger. I think (!?) Google does not provide Open API schemas for its libraries. Google provides an alternative to REST called [gRPC](https://grpc.io/) for some of its services. gRPC has its own code-generation mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

The `discovery.build()` method builds a service object (your `resource` variable) for the Google Python API client which allows you to easily use built-in methods to access API endpoints for a given API (in your case the `forms` API).

In your specific case, you can leverage your service object `resource` to make calls to any of the [Google Forms APIs](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest) in a much simpler way than specifying all the API endpoints directly.

Example using your `resource` service object to retrieve all responses to a Google form:

```py
# Prints the responses of your specified form:
form_id = '<YOUR_FORM_ID>'
result = resource.forms().responses().list(formId=form_id).execute()
print(result)
```

For more detailed examples with the Google Forms API see the [official developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/guides/retrieve-forms-responses)